# How to keep only the first element from a class when cloning with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each of my divs have a class attributes named `remove`, the `first` class has the `id: remove_item` then the `second` `remove_item_1`, the `third remove_item_2`, etc.

My problem is that i only want to clone first one with the id remove_item and remove all the other one from the clone.

If i do `clone.find('.remove');` i am able to gather all the elements with remove class but from there i am kinda lost on how to do that.

Could anyone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant code; it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think I understand, but can you supply the code you're currently using?

Comment: Cloning an element with an id will result in you having _two_ elements with the same id - and that will be invalid html.

Comment: do you mean to remove the first one with class .remove?
cause if you want to remove the div with id #remove_item you could just select it and remove it manually

Comment: @YESSINE no, i have an input form, i am cloning the whole input form, but in that input form i have an input that has multiple occurence ( i can add and delete them), so when cloning the whole input, i want to remove the previously added occurence for that input and just keep the orginal one so the one with only remove_item id

Comment: i still didn't get what you meant could you please include some code in your post?

Comment: @YESSINE there's kinda too much code to add, it's an mvc app i'd have to reproduce a simpler example. Basically my clone is my input form, and in that input form i have a section called Hospitalisation, where i can add multiple hospitalisation. So when i am cloning, i don't want all the added Hospitalisaiton, i just want to keep the first one which has the id remove_item

Answer (score 0):

You can keep first div by adding :first.

```
clone.find('.remove:first');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you mean

here's an example how to pick the first element of a cloned div:

lets say you have

```
<ul id="list">
        <div id="clone">
            <li class="remove remove1">Remove 1 </li>
            <li class="remove remove2">Remove 2</li>
            <li class="remove remove3">Remove 3</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

The script to clone the list and remove the first child of the clone goes like this :

```
<script>
        let clone = $('#clone').clone().appendTo('#list');
        clone.children().first().remove();
    </script>
```

or you can select the first one by class selection as @Manashree Shah mentioned like this:

```
clone.find('.remove:first');
```

The code uses jQuery, you can add this before the script if you haven't already added it :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```